# SQL Server: Difference between using max(date) in select vs using it in where clause

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT PositionToEffectDate as Current Date, PersonIdNo, PositionIdNo
  FROM tPERSON_POSITIONS
  WHERE PositionToEffectDate = (SELECT MAX(PositionToEffectDate) FROM tPERSON_POSITIONS)

GO

SELECT MAX(PositionToEffectDate) as CurrentDate, PersonIdNo, PositionIdNo
  FROM tPERSON_POSITIONS
  GROUP BY PersonIdNo,PositionIdNo,PositionToEffectDate
```

In above two queries I was trying to filter the result by current records but the first query is working fine while the second query is just displaying all the records instead of current records. Can you anyone please tell me why both the queries are displaying two different results?

Comment: You are grouping by PositionToEffectDate in the second query. Remove that from the group by.

Answer (score 0):

First Query display only record, where you are getting MAX(PositionToEffectDate), displaying person details belong that.

Second query, display one record for each PersonIdNo, PositionIdNo combination as you are doing group by. MAX(PositionToEffectDate) of PersonIdNo, PositionIdNo is displayed on each combination because of your select statment.

Comment: Even if I remove the group by clause in the second query it still doesn't filter the results by current records.

Answer (score 0):

First query will give you only the latest entry in the table based on PositionToEffectDate column whereas the second query would give you the latest record of each person base on your group by clause.

Note:In order to make your second query work properly, the PositionToEffectDate column has to be removed from the group by clause.

Comment: If I remove the PositionToEffectDate column from the group by clause it still gives me the same result.